# URL Rewrite to exclude existing directories

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect URLs from `example.net/customname` or `example.net/customname/` to example.net/my/home.php?username=customname .  This in itself is not complicated:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ my/home.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ my/home.php?username=$1
```

However, I want to exclude my existing directories and files, such as `example.net/about/` and `example.net/files`.  I can't quite figure out how to use RewriteCond (do I need multiple rewrite conds?) in order to exclude items like `example.net/about/` from being rewritten to `example.net/home.php?username=about`.  How can I do this?

Thank you!

**EDIT: Here is the exact solution...**

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ my/home.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Regarding your edit: why do you use two completely separate sets of rules whose only difference is a single character? It's verbose and inefficient, so I'd suggest using the option qualifier (the question mark) as localshred and I did in our answers.

Comment: Quite right, I changed my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RewriteCond` has some special patterns for exactly this purpose. Try this:

```
RewriteCond %REQUEST_FILENAME ! -d
RewriteCond %REQUEST_FILENAME ! -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ my/home.php?username=$1
```

Comment: I've seen the -d and -f before, but didn't realize that's what they did.  Thanks!  I posted my full syntactically correct solution above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RewriteCond (rewrite condition), similar to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^\/(about|files)\/?$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ my/home.php?username=$1 [L]
```

This would effectively only apply the rule if it gets through all the conditions above it, similar to using if statements.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond